# Receiving Content from Other Apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to register my app to receive files (of any type, not just images) from other apps. I'm following the [Receiving Content from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) tutorial.

I have:

1. Updated the app's manifest:

   ```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
       </intent-filter>
   ```
2. Implemented the `onCreate()` method of the activity:

   ```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String action = intent.getAction();
   String type = intent.getType();

   if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {            
       this.handleSend(intent);
   }
   ```
3. Implemented my private `handleSend()` method:

   ```
   void handleSend(Intent intent) {
       Uri fileUri = (Uri)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

       if (fileUri != null) {
            // OK, now?
       }
   }
   ```

If I print the `fileUri`, it is something like `content://downloads/all_downloads/5`. But how can I access its content?

Comment: have to tried to create a new File with that Uri?

Comment: what about `getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);`

Comment: See my answer to "Retrieve file name of content from other apps" here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16059369/237461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Selvin indicated, use `getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);` to get an `InputStream` on the contents of that `ContentProvider` `Uri`. The MIME type should be in the `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

change method as bellow

```
void handleSend(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            imageShare.setImageURI(imageUri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```