# Retrieve file name of content from other apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I have registered my app to receive files (of any type, not just images) from other apps following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568108/receiving-content-from-other-apps).

I have implemented the solution that was answered but I cannot find a way to retrieve the "file name" of the data stream.
As an example from an Uri like:

> content://downloads/all_downloads/5

I can get the stream out but I don't know anything about the name of the original file generating it.

Is there a way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to retrieve it?

Generally, no, because there may not be a name, in part because there may not be a file. You may be able to get an `InputStream` on the contents, but that does not mean that there is a file behind the `InputStream`.

There may be some specific hacks for some specific providers (e.g., `MediaStore`) to try to determine the file name associated with some data `Uri`, though such hacks may not be reliable.

Answer (score 4):

In MOST cases this will solve your problem:

```
Uri intentData = intent.getData();
    if (intentData != null) {
        String filePath;
        if("content".equals(intent.getScheme()))
        {
            filePath = getFilePathFromContentUri(intentData);
        }
        else
        {
            filePath = intentData.getPath();
        }
}

private String getFilePathFromContentUri(Uri selectedUri) {
    String filePath;
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaColumns.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> onCreate()

```
   Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        String action = intent1.getAction();
        String type = intent1.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            this.handleSend(intent1);
        }

 void handleSend(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            imageShare.setImageURI(imageUri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```